# leaks when using jni

Tags: c, java-native-interface, valgrind

I use *valgrind* to check memory leaks of a c program that invokes java method via *jni*. But even for the simplest program, which only creates a JVM and releases it, *valgrind* always reports leaks. Any suggestion?

```
  JNI_CreateJavaVM(&jvm, (void**)&env, &vm_args);
  (*jvm)->DestroyJavaVM(jvm);
```

The valgrind output:

```
> ==21794== 
> ==21794== HEAP SUMMARY:
> ==21794==     in use at exit: 7,596,470 bytes in 1,427 blocks
> ==21794==   total heap usage: 45,668 allocs, 44,241 frees, 25,184,437 bytes allocated
> ==21794== 
> ==21794== LEAK SUMMARY:
> ==21794==    definitely lost: 4,989 bytes in 24 blocks
> ==21794==    indirectly lost: 5,234 bytes in 22 blocks
> ==21794==      possibly lost: 245,199 bytes in 182 blocks
> ==21794==    still reachable: 7,341,048 bytes in 1,199 blocks
> ==21794==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
> ==21794== Rerun with --leak-check=full to see details of leaked memory
> ==21794== 
> ==21794== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
> ==21794== Use --track-origins=yes to see where uninitialised values come from
> ==21794== ERROR SUMMARY: 4040666 errors from 332 contexts (suppressed: 4 from 4)
```

Comment: Show the relevant valgrind output

Comment: do you really need to free the env? (maybe a stupid question, all the JNI I do is done the other way around, from Java)